# Perl, using variable from within While loop outside of the loop?

Tags: perl, variables, loops, scope, while-loop

This seems really simple but it is giving me a hard time figuring it out as I'm new to perl.. I've been looking through a lot of documentation now about loops and I am still stumped by this... I have a sub that contains a while loop and I want to use a variable value from within the loop outside of the loop (after the loop has run), however when I try to print out the variable, or return it out of the sub, it doesn't work, only when I print the variable from within the loop does it work.. I would appreciate any advice as to what I'm doing wrong.

Doesn't work (doesn't print $test ):

```
sub testthis {    
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= 2) {    
        my $test = 'its working' ;    
        $i++ ;
    }
    print $test ;
}

&testthis ;
```

Works, prints $test:

```
sub testthis {
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= 2) {
        my $test = 'its working' ;
        $i++ ;
        print $test ;
    }
}

&testthis ;
```

Comment: `$i = 1;` should probably be `my $i = 1;`, the way it is right now, you are talking to the variable `$i` in the outer scope which will be a source of errors as soon as you start calling subroutines from inside other subroutines.  Chances are that `$i` is not even declared in the outer scope, in which case you are talking to the package variable.  If you were running under `use strict; use warnings;` then the `strict` pragma would have thrown an error about the undeclared variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You declare variable test inside the loop, so it scope is the loop, as soon as you leave the loop the variable is not longer declared.
Add `my $test;` just between `$i=1` and `while(..)` and it will work. The scope will now be the entire sub instead of only the loop

Comment: ahh ok, I get it now.. thanks... the tutorials I've been looking at are too basic to even have mentioned this, I suppose I should go straight to the perl man pages from now on

Answer (score 5):

Place `my $test` before the while loop. Note that it will only contain the last value that is assigned in the while loop. Is that what you are after?

```
// will print "it's working" when 'the loop is hit at least once,
// otherwise it'll print "it's not working"
sub testthis {
    $i = 1;
    my $test = "it's not working";

    while ($i <= 2) {
        $test = "it's working";
        $i++ ;
    }
    print $test ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this one:

```
sub testthis {
my $test
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 2) {

$test = 'its working' ;

$i++ ;

print $test ;
}

}
```

&testthis ;

Note: whenever write perl code, its better to add `use strict;` and `use warning` in the beginning of the code.